# AJAX/PHP passar $_GET e $_POST?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, aplicação-web

Boa noite a todos, tenho um script PHP que cria uma tabela em que, nessa página é corrido um script ajax e dá para em tempo real ver quem está na database... nessa tabela tenho um botão delete para cada pessoa e ao clicar é criado um variable $_GET com o nº de processo (e.g searchstudent.php?usrdelete=5382 )

AJAX:

```
 $('#textbox').keyup(function(){
    $("#display_students").text('');
    var name = $('#textbox').val();
    if($.trim(name) != ''){
        $.post('../core/Query/students/student_search.php', {st_process: name}, function(data){
            $("#display_students").append(data);
        });

    }
});
```

PHP:

```
    <?php


if(isset($_POST['st_process']) === true && empty($_POST['st_process']) === false){
    include("../Query-core.php");
    include('../db.php');

        $authentication = new DBRequest($host = 'localhost',
                                $user = 'root',
                                $pass = '',
                                $db = 'contas');

        $selectedstudents = $authentication->selectionQueryLike("alunos", $authentication->e(trim($_POST['st_process'])), "student_process");

        if(mysqli_num_rows($selectedstudents) > 0){
            echo "<table><tr><th>Nome</th><th>NºProcesso</th><th>ID</th><th>Apagar</th></tr>";

            while($row =  $selectedstudents->fetch_assoc()){
               echo "<tr>";
               echo "<td><a href='#'>" . $row["student_name"] . "</a></td>";
               echo "<td>" . $row["student_process"] . "</td>";
               echo "<td>" . $row["student_ID"] . "</td>";
               echo "<td><a href=?usrdelete=" . $row["student_ID"] . ">Delete<a/></td>";

               echo "</tr>";

            }
            echo "</table>";
    }   
}

?>
```

como conseguiria passar simultaneamente o $_GET e o $_POST no ajax?

Answer (score 2):

Desta forma:

```
$.post('../core/Query/students/student_search.php?usrdelete=5382', {st_process: name}, function(data){
    $("#display_students").append(data);
});
```

Se for usar o valor de uma variavel basta concatenar a string usando o sinal de `+`, por exemplo:

```
var variavel = 5382;

$.post('../core/Query/students/student_search.php?usrdelete=' + variavel, {st_process: name}, function(data){
    $("#display_students").append(data);
});
```

GET é tudo que vai na querystring, ou seja na URL após o sinal de `?` e POST é tudo que vai no *payload* (no *body* da **requisição HTTP**), então a instrução HTTP de POST combinado com GET ficaria assim:

```
POST /pagina.php?getfoo=getbar HTTP/1.1 <--- aqui vai o GET (após o sinal de ?)
Host: foo.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 31 <--tamanho do body

postfoo=postbar&postbaz=postboo <-- body que contém o POST
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73917/discussion-on-answer-by-guilherme-nascimento-ajax-php-passar-get-e-post)